# batch rename files in Ubuntu: sequential numbering, based on order in directory. (Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: shell-script, rename, batch-jobs

[image]I had to download videos from DVR in more trials. After that files were manually arranged by alphabetical order into few groups, in each group  by numbers. It is necessary to have videos in former order and also to keep information about content for each file.

current situation:

a_1.(info about content).avi
a_2.(info about content)avi
...
a_101.(info about content).avi
b_1.(info about content).avi
b_2.(info about content).avi
...
b_350.(info about content).avi
..
..
..

It should look like:

1.(info about content).avi 2.(info about content).avi 3.(info about content).avi....500.(info about content).avi

Is there any way how to do it automatically?

Comment: Does the `(info about content)` contain any spaces?

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following command

```
i=1; for file in $(ls -v *.avi); do echo "$file --> $i.${file#*.}"; i=$((i+1)); done | less
```

Provided the `(info about content)` does not contain any space or newline characters, this shows you a mapping of source file to target file, so you can overlook if this is what you want. If you are happy with it, execute the line

```
i=1; for file in $(ls -v *.avi); do mv "$file" "$i.${file#*.}"; i=$((i+1)); done
```